# f statistic for multiple multivariate regression?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, multiple-regression, f-statistic

I've not seen an example of multiple multivariate regression use an F statistic, is it still valid here?  (Would the f stat follow the f distribution under the null hypothesis?)

### detail

Given n paired observations:

- $X \in \mathbb{R}^{a \times n}$ predictor variables ($a > 1$)

  - $a' < a$ of these are covariate (nuisance) variables
- $Y \in  \mathbb{R}^{b \times n}$ outcome variables ($b > 1$)

We estimate the minimum MSE mapping $\beta \in \mathbb{R}^{a \times b}$ from $x$ to $y$.

We're interested in rejecting the null hypothesis that there are only zero entries in the columns of $\beta$ associated with non-nuisance variables.  We compute the F statistic as:

$$F = \frac{RSS' - RSS}{RSS} \frac{n - ba}{b(a - a')}$$

where $RSS$ and $RSS'$ are the residual sum of squares associated with the full and reduced (covariate only) model respectively:

$$RSS = Tr (Y - \beta X)(Y - \beta X)^T$$

Under the null hypothesis, is this F distributed with $b(a - a'), n - ba$ degrees of freedom?

Answer (score 0):

The reference to the following text is Hayashi (Econometrics) Ch.3-4 (Proposition 3.3, 4.3).

Lets consider the model that satisfy the following list of assumptions:

1. (Linearity): There are $M$ linear equations
   \begin{equation}
   y_{im} = z_{im}^{'}\delta_m + \varepsilon_{im}, (m = 1, 2, \ldots, M; i = 1, \ldots, n),
   \end{equation}
   where $n$ is the sample size, $z_{im}$ is the $L_m$-dimensional vector of regressors, $\delta_m$ is the conformable coefficient vector, and $\varepsilon_{im}$ is an unobservable error term in the $m$-th equation.
2. (Ergodic stationarity): Let $x_{im}$ be the vector of $K_m$ instruments for the $m$-th equation. Let $w_i$ be unique and nonconstant elements of $(y_{i1}, \ldots, y_{iM}, z_{i1}, \ldots , z_{iM}, x_{i1}, \ldots , x_{iM})$. ${w_i}$ is jointly stationary and ergodic.
3. (Orthogonality conditions): For each equation $m$, the $K_m$ variables
   in $x_{im}$ are predetermined. That is, the following orthogonality conditions are
   satisfied:
   \begin{equation}
   E(x_{im}\varepsilon_{im}) = 0, (m = 1, 2, \ldots, M),
   \end{equation}
4. (Rank condition for identification): For each $m (= 1, 2, \ldots, M)$,
   $E(x_{im}z_{im}^{'})$ $(K_m \times L_m)$ is of full column rank.
5. ($g_i$ is a martingale difference sequence with finite second moments): Define
   \begin{equation}
   g_i = 
   \begin{bmatrix}
   x_{i1}\varepsilon_{i1} \\
   \vdots \\
   x_{iM}\varepsilon_{iM}
   \end{bmatrix}
   \end{equation}
   ${g_i}$ is a joint martingale difference sequence. $E(g_{i} g_{i}^{'})$ is nonsingular.

Proposition 4.3 (robust t-ratio and Wald statistics): Suppose Assumptions 1-5 hold, and suppose there is available a consistent estimate $\hat{S}$ of $S (= Avar(g) =
E(g_{i} g_{i}^{'})$. Let
\begin{equation}
\widehat{Avar(\hat{\delta}(\hat{W}))} = (S_{xz}^{'}\hat{W}S_{xz})^{-1} S_{xz}^{'}\hat{W}\hat{S}\hat{W}S_{xz} (S_{xz}^{'}\hat{W}S_{xz})^{-1}
\end{equation}

Then: Under the null hypothesis $H_0: R\delta = r$ where $\#r$ is the number of restrictions (the dimension of $r$) and $R (\#r \times L)$ is of full row rank,
\begin{equation}
Wald_{test} = n (R \hat{\delta}(\hat{W}) - r)^{'} \{R \widehat{Avar(\hat{\delta}(\hat{W}))} R^{'}\} (R \hat{\delta}(\hat{W}) - r) \to_d \chi^2(\#r)
\end{equation}